# AWS - Get user token from an existing Cognito User Pool with username and password on an existing React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a simple React web app created from `create-react-app`.

I also have an existing user pool (set up by a third party) on Amazon Cognito. I have been given a username and password for authentication. Once authenticated, Cognito provides a JWT token.

What I want to achieve is to authenticate the user and get a JWT access_token within the `componentDidMount` method of the `App` component; then use the token to call other APIs to retrieve some data and then show the data on the `App` component.

The following info is known:

```
region
USER_POOL_ID
APP_CLIENT_ID
USER_ACCOUNT
USER_PASSWORD
```

AWS provides the `authenticate_and_get_token` function for Python developers. Is there an equivalent for JavaScript and React developers? Any sample code is appreciated.

Comment: did you try just using amplify? - https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the `authenticate_and_get_token` you mentioned, couln't find this function in [Boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).
But I do know different function to retrieve a token called [`adminInitiateAuth`](http://adminInitiateAuth). This is function available for JS.

you can implement this using Lambda, like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const USER_POOL_ID  = "us-east-1_*******";
const APP_CLIENT_ID = "***********";
const USER_ACCOUNT  = "***********";
const USER_PASSWORD = "***********";

const cognitoClient = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    apiVersion: "2016-04-19",
    region: 'us-east-1'
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const userData = await userSignIn(USER_ACCOUNT, USER_PASSWORD);
        return userData // refer to userData.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
    } catch(e){
        throw e;
    }

};

const userSignIn = async (username, password) => {
    try {
        var params = {
            AuthFlow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',     
            ClientId: APP_CLIENT_ID ,     
            UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,     
            AuthParameters: {         
                USERNAME: username,        
                PASSWORD: password
            } 
        };
        
        return await cognitoClient.adminInitiateAuth(params).promise();
    } catch (err) {
        return err.message ? err : {message : err};
    }
};
```

Please make sure you have the specific permission to invoke this method, like `"Action": "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",` in the lambda permissions, or in IAM role.